# jquery.load not working with files that contain partial html

Tags: jquery, html

I have an empty scriptblock:

```
 <script id="target" type="text/html"></script>
```

I am using

```
 jQuery("#target").load(...)
```

to load the contents of a few seperate files into a target scriptblock

To simplify, file1 contains starthtml, file2 contains some various html containing ALL begin AND end tags and file3 contains endhtml

file 2 loads perfect, file 1 and 3 however will not load OR just load partially while I get a success status from the load. It seems like there is some contruction (not ending started tags or vice verca) or some character in the htmlcode in my template that will not load into the scriptblock.

Here is the real content that will not display in my codeblock after loading:

```
        </td>
        <td width="1px" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="1px" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- *** END WRAPPER TABLE *** -->

</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

<!-- *** END HMTL *** -->
```

If I replace the content above with more simple html like blow, then it works fine

```
 </td></tr></table>
```

What could be the cause and is there a solution or workaround?

Comment: First off, why are you loading this in a script block ?

Comment: The closing `</html>` tag is probably one problem. You can only have one of those. Period. You can't embed a full HTML document within another full HTML document via a `<script>` tag. Not even sure where you got the idea you could.

Comment: Try ajax() with dataType set to 'html' but maybe the HTML not displaying is because the html tags are not well ballanced / valid.  Maybe you you start with a </tr> after the wrapper

Comment: @Interstallar_Coder > I got a page where you can drag and drop templates to build a layout for a newsletter. then when you click generate it will put the html code for in a textarea for the user to copy and paste. Instead of fetching the templates when the user clicks generate I want to pre-load the html snippets in hidden script blocks on the page.

Comment: @ChrisPratt > the closing html is not the problem, I have tested it. Note that the html will not get rendered > its just holding it there to be show in a textarea later for the user to copy.

Comment: @Juan > I don't need a html datatype, I just want any content to load in the scriptblock for later usage in generating a template. But thanks for proposing to try with .ajax() I did rewrite it with .ajax() and that got me towards the solution, posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found the source of the problem and the solution.

The problem with **jQuery.load** for what I want to do is that it **will set the .html of the target** element. setting the .html with jQuery **will cause jQuery to parse/evaluate the content** that is returned from the server for valid html since the .load method is created as a shortcut for loading content into your page.

If jQuery.ajax is used the parsing will not take place, it just gets the result from the server and I can do any processing myself, including putting the content in the element I want. **instead of** setting the content of the scriptblock with **.html** I can now set it using **.text** which will not parse the content.

This way I can set any content in my scriptblock which will be used later to to create a html template/layout for display in a textarea so it is available to the user to copy.